# Directus custom interface - reload collection entry data

Tags: directus

I am trying to build a custom collection interface where if the user clicks on the reload button, the item content should be "refreshed". Is this possible?

I saw in JS there is a this.api, where the API functions can be called, but I am not sure how to reload the data for the current collection item.

Any suggestions?

[image]

`display.vue`

```js
<template>
  <div>
    <button @click="noClick">
      <v-icon
        v-tooltip="Execute"
        class="material-icons select"
        name="play_arrow"
      />
    </button>
    <button @click="noClick">
      <v-icon v-tooltip="Execute" class="material-icons select" name="replay" />
    </button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import mixin from "@directus/extension-toolkit/mixins/interface";

export default {
  mixins: [mixin],
  data: {
    count: 0,
  },
  computed: {
    now: function() {
      console.log(this);
      return Date.now();
    },
    displayValue() {
      return "uolo";
      if (this.value) return this.value.toLowerCase();
    },
  },
  methods: {
    warn: function(message, event) {
      // now we have access to the native event
      if (event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        event.preventDefault();
      }
    },
    noClick: function(event) {
      // now we have access to the native event
      if (event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        event.preventDefault();
      }
      debugger;
    },
  },
};
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
div {
  background-color: var(--gray-300);
  border-radius: var(--border-radius);
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no official way to trigger a refresh on the page.

Though a little hacky, the best option would be to hack your way up through the parent tree using `this.$parent` and calling `getItems()` once you make your way up to the `v-items` component https://github.com/directus/app/blob/f8ead9ff31964ca998f8d1807123046e489a0f7f/src/components/items.vue#L220